# If the universe stopped expanding, when would we realize it?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion

Suppose in this moment the universe stopped expanding, how long would if take and how would we register the change?

Since the bodies are still and it is space that is expanding in between, we wouldn't notice the change even if the expansion would completely stop in a short time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few million to about 30 million years from now. I.e., we'd be able to measure a change in the previously observed redshifts for galaxies a few to about 10 Mega parsecs away. A parsec is a little more than 3 light years.

The reason is that closer in galaxies are in our local group or cluster, and we are to a great extent gravitationally bounded to them. Our relative velocities then depend more on each other than the cosmological expansion. If we go further then the cosmological expansion starts becoming the dominant effect. We would have to see more than one Galaxy doing that, but it certainly would be deemed as totally unexpected to see even one radically having changed its velocity.

Of course, since it might have happened a few to 30 million years ago, we could start seeing that tomorrow.

Now, something huge cosmologically had to happen for the expansion to stop. Maybe some huge increase in the matter density. If so, we might see some of that in more local galaxies, maybe even ours, as we would see the local gravitational effects. So we actually then would discover it pretty quickly, say a year or two for astronomers to realize they are seeing something and not simply errors in everything they calculate from more local observations. If not an increase in mass or energy density, then some strange field would have settled to some value other than its current one, and again it could affect things everywhere. If it happened 30 million light years away we'd wait the same time as in my first answer.

But none of that makes much sense.

Comment: How what? How it could stop? I think I explained, you'd have to instantaneously somehow add a lot of matter energy. It seems to me it'd take some time to stop. So, really pretty unphysical. There has been speculation that the Higgs field is close to an unstable value, and if it got somehow shoved (?) it could become so. Another expanding bubble would start Someplace, and reach us. We'd disappear as it reached us, so we wouldn't feel anything or see anything before. But it's all speculation. The only reality is we see the expansion for a distance of  a few to 30 light years away at closest.

Comment: 1) if space expanded at c (or at even c+) in a Planck time,, why couldn't it stop as apruptly in same unit? 2) how would we know it? 2) why couldn't we earlier notice shift- changes in nearer star?

Comment: It could if the equations of state of the - call it - de-inflaton field had a very large pressure and energy. The inflaton field had negative pressure, causing the expansion, the new field would have positive pressure. It may also need to have other properties such as the exact energy pressure tourist stop it, maybe to stop it quickly it would need to overdo it and cause a big universal implosion. Noticing an earlier shift would be impossible, the new field would propagate at c (or more, I'd need to research but doubt it) and so it'd be the first thing we'd see or feel.

Comment: Shouldn't we notice the change in red-shift of light which was released even in our own galaxy?

Comment: No, our galaxy is dominated by its own gravity, expansion or not is not measurable. Our Galaxy is about 100,000 light years across, we need a few million light years min. to be able to measure a redshift from cosmology.  We also would not notice it from our neighbors galaxies like Andromeda. In any event, if we did, we would see that at the same time we see it affecting us, like destroying us, since it would travel at the speed of light. We would not see the light or notice anything from other bodies till we saw that field also affecting us.